# Filtering transform over time

Tags: ros, filter, ar-kinect, quaternion, ar-pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ar_kinect and I'm getting some noise in the orientation. Since my camera motion is relatively slow I wanted to filter the transforms over time. I have designed an FIR filter. I was wondering what is the best way of filtering the transformations.

I was not sure if filtering quaternions would make any sense. Should I convert to RPY and apply the filter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29323/filtering-transform-over-time/) by [ravenII](https://answers.ros.org/users/1831/ravenii/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2012-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should filter on the quaternions.  Their main value is that they don't have singularities and can be cleanly interpolated, which are important if you want to filter.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2